# Precision specifier as parameter like printf but in String.Format

Tags: c#, string, printf, string-formatting

Using printf i could specify the precision value as an extra parameter using *.  Does the same functionality exist in the C# String.Format?

**edit:** For example:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:D*}",1,4); // Outputs 0001
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, String.Format does not support the star operator. You'd need to use either string concatenation

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:D" + myPrecision.ToString() + "}",1);
```

or nested `String.Format`s

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{{0:D{0}}}", 4), 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

Formatting the format string should do the trick:

```
var number = 1;
var width = 4;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{{0:D{0}}}", width), number);
```

It will output `0001`.

Notice how `{{` and `}}` are used to escape `{` and `}` in a format string.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is possible.  You just need to add the precision number after the format specifier.  For example

```
Console.WriteLine("{0:D4}",1); // Outputs 0001;
```

What the precision modifier does is specific to the format type chosen though.  In this case the D stands for Decimal output.  Here is a link to the types of numeric formats and what the precision means for each of them.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Comment: No, what I want is:
Console.WriteLine("{0:D*}",1,4); // Outputs 0001;

Comment: So then the answer to your question is no, @Sprintstar, c# implements similar syntax with the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround is similar to how Qt implements `QString::arg()`. I just put a placeholder and then replaced it with the value of `numericPrecision`.

```
numericPrecision = "N2";
var summary = string.Format(
    "{0}: {1:_np_}, {2}: {3:_np_}, {4}: {5:_np_}".Replace("_np_", numericPrecision),
    title1, value1,
    title2, value2,
    title3, value3);
```

Answer (score 0):

To format a string that is left justified for specified length.

```
int len = 20;
string fmt = string.Format( "{{0,-{0}}}", len );
string name = string.Format( fmt, "a persons name" );
```

or

```
name.PadRight( len );
```

The result should be a name that is padded on the right for a total length of 20 characters.